# Switched my Rails database to PostgreSQL for Heroku, and now the app can't access the DB at all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm really stumped on this one. I've tried so many things.

I had to switch from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL so I can deploy on Heroku. Everything worked fine when I ran it locally. There's one error that happens after I git push heroku master. It starts to deploy and I get this:

`Rails couldn't infer whether you are using multiple databases from your database.yml and can't generate the tasks for the non-primary databases. If you'd like to use this feature, please simplify your ERB.`

Which also happens when I run `heroku rake` except it's followed by this:

`rake aborted! Psych::BadAlias: Cannot load database configuration: Unknown alias: default`

followed by stack trace.

I assume I screwed something up along the way. I just don't know what it's expecting, or where I should be looking. My database.yml looks like this:

`production: adapter: postgresql encoding: utf8 pool: 15 <<: *default url: *db url from heroku* timeout: 5000`

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm new to all this. i've tried dropping and reseting the db. The last bit of evidence I can provide is the log from Heroku:

`heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ohmydog.herokuapp.com request_id=6217a180-f9ef-43da-8bb0-fc5d064e11fb fwd="185.232.22.206" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

Comment: Hi Brian, can you post your full database.yml file? the idea is to look in the 'default' entry.

Comment: thank you, the below comment helped to get rid of that error, but I'm seeing another so I will post there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have to do close to no configuration to get Postgres to work on Heroku as it provides the almost the entire configuration via [ENV["DATABASE_URL"]](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database) which is automatically merged with (and takes precedence over) the settings from `database.yml`.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 15 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_test

production:
  <<: *default
```

This is actually a fully functioning config for `Postgres.app` locally and Heroku. I would really leave almost everything at the defaults and only [tune the DB](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-database-tuning) if needed. Prefer using `ENV["DATABASE_URL"]` locally as well for setting stuff like passwords and usernames as it avoids developer wars.

Comment: Thank you!  I was actually able to get it to this point before, and I get the following error:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2020-01-07T00:03:44.787597+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 8:  WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2020-01-07T00:03:44.787600+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
`

This is from my Heroku logs as well

Comment: `PG::UndefinedTable` errors usually are telling you that you forgot to run the migrations that create the tables.

Comment: You have to run the migrations both locally and on heroku with `heroku run rails db:migrate`.

Comment: I knew I was missing something. THANK YOU SO MUCH! I thought it was something much bigger lol.